# Recursion on a table in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, recursion

My XML is several 100 movie elements long and i'm trying to create a table for each genre, where each row of the table is a SET amount of  elements, each  containing a single movie.

Here is my xml (greatly simplified and shortened, in my real deal there are 100s of 'movie' elements)

```
    <mediaList>
        <movie>
        <title>16 Blocks</title>
        <director>Richard Donner</director>
        <genreWrap>
            <genre>Action and Adventure</genre>
            <subGenre>Action Thrillers</subGenre>
            <subGenre>Crime Action</subGenre>
        </genreWrap>
    </movie>

    <movie>
         <title>Armageddon</title>
        <director>Michael Bay</director>
        <genreWrap>
            <genre>Action and Adventure</genre>
            <subGenre>Deadly Disasters</subGenre>
        </genreWrap>
    </movie>

    <movie>
        <title>African Queen, The</title>
        <director>John Huston</director>
        <genreWrap>
            <genre>Action and Adventure</genre>
            <subGenre>Action Classics</subGenre>
            <subGenre>Adventures</subGenre>
        </genreWrap>
    </movie>

    <movie>
        <title>Assault on Precinct 13</title>
        <director>Jean-François Richet</director>
        <genreWrap>
            <genre>Action and Adventure</genre>
            <subGenre>Action Thrillers</subGenre>
            <subGenre>Crime Action</subGenre>
        </genreWrap>
    </movie>
    <movie>
        <title>Back to the Future 3 (Box Set)</title>
        <director>Robert Zemeckis</director>
        <genreWrap>
            <genre>Action and Adventure</genre>
            <subGenre>Westerns</subGenre>
        </genreWrap>
    </movie>

    <movie>
        <title>Billy Budd</title>
        <director>Peter Ustinov</director>
        <genreWrap>
            <genre>Action and Adventure</genre>
            <subGenre>Action Classics</subGenre>
            <subGenre>Adventures</subGenre>
        </genreWrap>
    </movie>

    <movie>
        <title>Black Arrow</title>
        <director>Gordon Douglas</director>
        <genreWrap>
            <genre>Action and Adventure</genre>
            <subGenre>Adventures</subGenre>
            <subGenre>Super Swashbucklers</subGenre>
        </genreWrap>
    </movie>

    <movie>
        <title>Black Cat Run</title>
        <director>D.J. Caruso</director>
        <genreWrap>
            <genre>Action and Adventure</genre>
            <subGenre>Action Thrillers</subGenre>
        </genreWrap>
    </movie>

    <movie>
         <title>Captains Courageous</title>
        <director>Victor Fleming</director>
        <genreWrap>
            <genre>Action and Adventure</genre>
            <subGenre>Action Classics</subGenre>
            <subGenre>Adventures</subGenre>
        </genreWrap>
    </movie>

    <movie>
       <title>Brothers Grimm, The</title>
        <director>Terry Gilliam</director>
        <genreWrap>
            <genre>Action and Adventure</genre>
            <subGenre>Adventures</subGenre>
        </genreWrap>
    </movie>

    <movie>
        <title>Convoy</title>
        <director>Sam Peckinpah</director>
        <genreWrap>
            <genre>Action and Adventure</genre>
            <subGenre>Action Comedies</subGenre>
        </genreWrap>
    </movie>

<movie>
 <title>Deliverance</title>
        <director>John Boorman</director>
        <genreWrap>
            <genre>Action and Adventure</genre>
            <subGenre>Action Classics</subGenre>
            <subGenre>Action Thrillers</subGenre>
            <subGenre>Adventures</subGenre>
        </genreWrap>
</movie>
</mediaList>
```

and my stylesheet

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="html"/>

    <xsl:key name="genre" match="genre" use="."/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each
            select="mediaList/movie/genreWrap/genre[local-name() = 'genre'][generate-id()=generate-id(key('genre', .)[1])]">
            <xsl:variable name="genre" select="."/>
            <xsl:result-document method="html" href="GenreHTML/{translate(.,' ','')}.html">
                <html>
                    <head>
                        <title>
                            <xsl:value-of select="translate(.,' ','')"/>
                        </title>
                    </head>
                    <body>
                        <table class="genre">
                            <tr>
                                <xsl:variable name="movies">
                                    <xsl:apply-templates select="key('genre', .)/ancestor::movie">
                                        <xsl:sort/>
                                    </xsl:apply-templates>
                                </xsl:variable>
                                <xsl:copy-of select="subsequence($movies/td,1,6)"/>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </body>
                </html>
            </xsl:result-document>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="movie">
        <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
        </td>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I know that right now I'm using this sequence function which will just print the first 6, I'm trying to figure out how to do it recursively so it will print 6  on EACH

desired output:

```
<html>
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
      <title>ActionandAdventure</title>
</head>
   <body>
      <table class="genre">
         <tr>
            <td>16 Blocks</td>
            <td>African Queen, The</td>
            <td>Armageddon</td>
            <td>Assault on Precinct 13</td>
            <td>Back to the Future 3 (Box Set)</td>
            <td>Billy Budd</td>
         </tr>
<tr>
<td>Black Arrow</td>
<td>Black Cat Run</td>
<td>Brothers Grimm, The</td
<td>Captains Courageous</td>
<td>Convoy</td>
<td>Deliverance</td>
</tr>
      </table>
   </body>
</html>
```

I'm using XSLT 2.0, but I'll take anything ya got! I deliberately pulled all the xml examples from one genre, but be assured that the real one has many movies with many different genres

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using XSLT 2.0, then there is no real need to use Muenchian grouping here, as powerful as it is, you can use **xsl:for-each-group**

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="movie" group-by="genreWrap/genre">
```

Then, to 'split' each group of movie into rows of 6, use **xsl:for-each** to select the **movie** elements that will occur as the first cell of each row (i.e the ones in the 1st, 7th, 13th, etc positions)

```
<xsl:for-each select="current-group()[position() mod 6 = 1]">
```

To select the elements in the row, you would then do this (because within the context of the **xsl:for-each** the `position()` will be set as 1, 2, 3, etc, but you need elements in their actual position, which will be 1, 7, 13, etc.)

```
<xsl:apply-templates 
     select="current-group()[position() >= ($pos - 1) * 6 + 1 and position() &lt; ($pos - 1) * 6 + 7]" />
```

In XSLT 2.0, you don't even need recursion if you have less than 6 movies in a row. You can just use a **xsl:for-each** loop

```
<xsl:for-each select="1 to 6 - (count(current-group()) mod 6)">
     <td></td>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="html"/>

    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <xsl:for-each-group select="movie" group-by="genreWrap/genre">
            <xsl:variable name="genre" select="."/>
            <xsl:result-document method="html" href="GenreHTML/{translate(current-grouping-key(),' ','')}.html">
                <html>
                    <head>
                        <title>
                            <xsl:value-of select="translate(current-grouping-key(),' ','')"/>
                        </title>
                    </head>
                    <body>
                        <table class="genre">
                            <xsl:for-each select="current-group()[position() mod 6 = 1]">
                                <xsl:variable name="pos" select="position()" />
                                    <tr>
                                        <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()[position() >= ($pos - 1) * 6 + 1 and position() &lt; ($pos - 1) * 6 + 7]" />
                                        <xsl:if test="not(current-group()[($pos - 1) * 6 + 6])">
                                            <xsl:for-each select="1 to 6 - (count(current-group()) mod 6)">
                                                <td></td>
                                            </xsl:for-each>
                                        </xsl:if>
                                    </tr>
                            </xsl:for-each>
                        </table>
                    </body>
                </html>
            </xsl:result-document>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="movie">
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
        </td>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

EDIT: I hadn't taken sorting into account in this answer. If you want the movies sorted, then currently the only way I can think of doing it is sorting them, and storing the results in a variable, and then iterating over that as before.

Try this XSLT (which should also take into account case-sensitivity on the title, but sorting on the title in upper case):

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="html"/>

    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <xsl:for-each-group select="movie" group-by="genreWrap/genre">
            <xsl:variable name="genre" select="."/>
            <result-document method="html" href="GenreHTML/{translate(current-grouping-key(),' ','')}.html">
                <html>
                    <head>
                        <title>
                            <xsl:value-of select="translate(current-grouping-key(),' ','')"/>
                        </title>
                    </head>
                    <body>
                        <table class="genre">
                            <xsl:variable name="sorted-group">
                                <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
                                    <xsl:sort select="upper-case(title)" />
                                    <xsl:copy-of select="." />
                                </xsl:for-each>
                            </xsl:variable>
                            <xsl:for-each select="$sorted-group/movie[position() mod 6 = 1]">
                                <xsl:variable name="pos" select="position()" />
                                <xsl:apply-templates select="$sorted-group/movie[6]" />
                                <tr>
                                    <xsl:for-each select="$sorted-group/movie[position() >= ($pos - 1) * 6 + 1 and position() &lt; ($pos - 1) * 6 + 7]">
                                        <td>
                                            <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
                                        </td>
                                    </xsl:for-each>
                                    <xsl:if test="not($sorted-group/movie[($pos - 1) * 6 + 6])">
                                        <xsl:for-each select="1 to 6 - (count($sorted-group/movie) mod 6)">
                                            <td></td>
                                        </xsl:for-each>
                                    </xsl:if>
                                </tr>
                            </xsl:for-each>
                        </table>
                    </body>
                </html>
            </result-document>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Hm -- that didn't produce my desired result. Some <tr> had fewer than 6 <td> while other <tr> had more! Also the movies were no longer sorted alphabetically by title. Is the fact that I didn't include more <movie> elements in my example confusing? there are 51 <movie>s in the genre, Action and Adventure for example and I didn't want to overwhelm my post.

Comment: @user3708965 - Sorry, I have spotted my blunder (due to `position()` being context sensitive). I have re-jigged my answer to hopefully give you the desired results now!

Comment: Oh wow! thanks so much -- I'm going to work through this example to better understand it, but it really helps, thank you!    One thing that I think keeps tripping me up due to that context sensitivity, is having trouble keeping the alphabetical order sorted correctly. Once I go a layer deeper with a for-each-group the sorting just seems to stop workin...

Comment: @user3708965 - I hadn't taken sorting into account in my previous answer. I have no added an alternate solution, which does do sorting.